# How to get the latest price update using Google Spreadsheet Query?

Tags: google-sheets

i have some problem when using query to get latest price,

click
[Query screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdZX3.png)

I tried using max method on date, but its not working, how i should do it properly?

I want the query result showing newest data based on most recent date

Comment: Sorry picture is not show and data i copy from google sheet is become hard to read,
Please click "Query example" link, its a picture i screenshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SORTN()` with `ties_mode` parameter `2` (2 indicate remove duplicates) may work.

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:C7,1,0),99^9,2,2,0)
```

If you need to sort it by `name` then use another `SORT()` function.

```
=SORT(SORTN(SORT(A2:C7,1,0),99^9,2,2,0),2,1)
```

[***SORTN***](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) google document reference.

Another way to use `REDUCE()` function. Try-

```
=REDUCE(A1:C1,UNIQUE(B2:B),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,CHOOSEROWS(SORT(FILTER(A2:C,B2:B=x),1,0),1))))
```

[image]

> ***Edit:*** To use `QUERY()` function you need few more function to organize data first. Try-

```
=QUERY(QUERY(CHOOSEROWS(A2:C,BYROW(B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B)),LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A=MAXIFS(A2:A,B2:B,x))*(B2:B=x)))))),
"select max(Col1),Col2,max(Col3) group by Col2"),"offset 1",0)
```

Comment: thanks, sort method maybe create another problem when data become big, maybe there is query method?

Comment: @SalmonNona Can you please try my edited answer?

Comment: thanks! your code works!
and it solve another problem when data is growing

Comment: @SalmonNona `B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B)` This part solve the issue of data growing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to return the last non-empty row in A:C, you can use:

```
=XLOOKUP(MAX(A:A),A:A,A:C)
```

Comment: not the non-empty row, but return biggest date value, and its using query

Comment: if the dates are sorted in ascending order, that's the equivalent of returning the last non-empty row of the range. The solution I provided is pretty straightforward, why do you need to use QUERY?

Comment: your code is not work btw, it only show one result, i dont understand non-empty row you mean, but it just easier to modify using query